# O365 API get room list with REST

Tags: exchangewebservices, office365

Is that possible to get a list of room mailboxes available on an Exchange tenant?

I've been searching for a method to get that information and although I found that method by using SOAP I've been unable to find a way to do it using REST.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your question!  Office 365 REST APIs for Calendar don't yet support this functionality.  It is on our roadmap, but the timeframe isn't decided.  Can you please tell me a little bit about your scenario?

You can use Exchange Web Services (EWS) SOAP APIs for now to get set of room lists and individual rooms within a room list.  See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/dn643730(v=exchg.150).aspx) for more info on using the .NET EWS Managed API or directly make EWS SOAP requests for this scenario.

Let me know if you have any questions or need more info.

Thanks,

Venkat

Comment: I'm writing an iOS App that must manage room mailboxes so I would be great to do so by using REST. Nevertheless SOAP it's also an option. By the way I have another question regarding the authentication with O365 tenant without using OAuth. I'll make this question on a separate thread. Thank you for your help, and keep that great work!

Comment: Thanks, SantiF dezMunoz!  I will pass on your feedback to the team :)

Comment: Thanks Venkat. Just for information, if it could help, I also rose a feature request on the Yammer Office365 group.